# How to assign a Future Map to a static variable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, static, future

I want to collect all data and throw them into one map variable:

```
//function
  Future<Map<String, String>?> getLoginUser() async{
    Map<String,String> ?userLoginInfo;
      userTable!.get().then((res) {
        var data = res.data;
        userLoginInfo!.update(data['userEmail'],data['userPwd']);
      });
    return userLoginInfo;
  }
```

```
//I want to use the above function
Map<String,String>mockUsers=.getLoginUser() as Map<String, String>;
```

However it just waste time when running,could anyone tell me how to use this future one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async` keyword removes/simplifies the usage of `then()`

```dart
Future<Map<String, String>?> getLoginUser() async{
    Map<String,String>? userLoginInfo;
    var data = (await userTable!.get()).data;
    userLoginInfo!.update(data['userEmail'],data['userPwd']);
    return userLoginInfo;
  }
```

Usage

```dart
Map<String,String> mockUsers = await getLoginUser()!;
```

or

```dart
Map<String,String>? mockUsers = await getLoginUser();
```